# Mailbox doesn't exit with Get-MailboxFolder but exist with Get-Mailbox

Tags: exchange-server

When I type the command :

> Get-Mailbox "user"

It returns the mailbox of "user" without problem but when I want to access the folders of "user" with :

> Get-MailboxFolder "user"

I have this error message : "The specified mailbox doesn't exist".

I specify that I have full access on the "user"'s mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code：

```
Get-MailboxFolder -Identity user:\user -Recurse
```

This code is to get information about all the subfolders under the user folder in the user mailbox.
If the above code doesn't solve the problem, you can see if your user folder is in the root directory, and if not, change the file path,for example:

```
Get-MailboxFolder -Identity user:\yourfoldername\user -Recurse
```